# R: object "Regression.Kernel" not found

Tags: r

I'm trying to process the data ("final_ts") in order to make a forecast for the time series using kernel functions and doing parallel computing. The analysis is made this way: 1) analyse the empirical time series, 2) run a standard variable
selection to subset only those variables and their time-lags that provide the best validation error. 3) Run the same analysis described above to choose the optimal regularization parameters and kernel function of the regularized algorithm. As a result I show the RMSE (root mean squared error).

The code is not mine, and I'm trying to set it without problems, but as I do not have so much experience, I can't understand how to solve (I've spent 2 days trying to find the solution so if you help me I would be so grateful) the problem which occured: "The object '....' not found".

So the MAIN CODE looks like this (I'll try to make explanation on what happens, please don't judge me):

```
#download the libraries:

#rm(list=ls(all=TRUE)) 
suppressMessages(library(Matrix))
suppressMessages(library(quantreg))
suppressMessages(library(parallel))
suppressMessages(library(compiler))
suppressMessages(library(lars))
suppressMessages(library(elasticnet))
suppressMessages(library(caret))
options(warn=-1)

#####################################################################################
#Download the sources (I'll show them in the end as a code)

###########Take the file###
ShowPlot = FALSE
lags = TRUE
ModelName = 'final_ts'
FileName = paste(ModelName, '.txt', sep = '')
########Calculate the logspace and the standard error functions #################
logspace <- function(d1, d2, n) exp(log(10)*seq(d1, d2, length.out=n)) 
std_err <- function(x) sd(x)/sqrt(length(x))
############# Choose the kernel function: we have 4 of them, but we try the second one #####
Kernel.Options = c('Exponential.Kernel', 'Epanechnikov.Kernel', 'TriCubic.Kernel', 'Matern.Kernel')
Regression.Kernel = Kernel.Options[1]

############# Choose the parameters for cross validation ####
lambda = logspace(-3,0,15) 
if(Regression.Kernel == 'Exponential.Kernel'){
  tht = seq(from = 0., to = 10, length = 30)         
}else{
  tht = seq(from = 0.1, to = 3, length = 20)     
}
parameters_on_grid = expand.grid(tht, lambda)     
### Read Time series
d = as.matrix(read.table(FileName, header= T))
######################
original.Embedding = c('Pro', 'Syn','Piceu')
original.TargetList = original.Embedding
d = d[, original.Embedding]
#### Here you take combinations of lags (best lag are 1 - 2) #####
x.lag = 1; y.lag = 2; z.lag = 1
sp.lag.selection = c(x.lag, y.lag, z.lag)
lagged.time.series = make.lagged.ts(d, sp.lag.selection)
d = lagged.time.series$time.series
original.col = lagged.time.series$original.variables
if(lags == TRUE){ var.sel = original.col; }else{ var.sel = colnames(d)}
##### Names and embedding in the laged dataset
if(lags == TRUE){ colnames(d) = Embedding =  TargetList = LETTERS[1:ncol(d)]}else{
  Embedding =  TargetList = original.Embedding
}
##### length of training and test set (2 points for testing, 7 - for training)
length.testing = 2
length.training = nrow(d) - length.testing
#### Preserve training for the interactions
ts.train.preserved = d[1:length.training, var.sel]
std.ts.train = Standardizza(ts.train.preserved)
#### Preserve testing for the test (you want your algorithm to learn the real structure of the model)
ts.test.preserved = d[(length.training + 1):nrow(d), var.sel]
#### Training set:
d.training = Standardizza(d[1:length.training, ])
#### You now need to standardize the test set using mean and sd of the training set
d.testing = Standardizza.test(ts.test.preserved,ts.train.preserved)
############## Prepare for parallel computing
Lavoratori = detectCores() - 2
cl <- parallel::makeCluster(Lavoratori, setup_strategy = "sequential")
####
RegressionType = ELNET_fit_

alpha = 0.85

### should you compute all the variables or not?
BestModel = BestModelLOOCV(cl, d.training, TargetList, Embedding, parameters_on_grid, RegressionType,alpha)
```

I also found a fourmula for calculation of kernel function (it may be put in a SPECIAL r (SOURCE 1)):

```
Exponential.Kernel <- function(dst, theta){
  dbar <- mean(dst)
  krnl <- exp(-theta*dst/dbar)
  return(krnl)
}
Exponential.Kernel <- cmpfun(Exponential.Kernel)
```

The formulas for finding the best leave-one-out cross-validation parameters is below (SOURCE 2):

```
########################### Cross Validation (Leave-one-out) ##################################

BestModelLOOCV <- function(cl, X, TargetList, Embedding, grid, RegressionType,alpha){
  mine_output = Jacobian_(cl, X, TargetList, Embedding, grid, RegressionType,alpha)
  theta_opt = mine_output$th
  lambda_opt = mine_output$lm
 mine_c0  = mine_output$c0
  mine_output = mine_output$J
  
  J_ = list()
  C0_ = do.call(cbind, lapply(1:ncol(X), function(x, M) unlist(M[[x]]), mine_c0))
  colnames(C0_) = sapply(TargetList,function(x) paste("c0_", x, sep = ""))
  for(k in 1:(nrow(X) - 1)){
    J_[[k]] = do.call(rbind, lapply(1:ncol(X), function(x, M, i) unlist(M[[x]][i,]), mine_output, k))
    rownames(J_[[k]]) = Embedding
    colnames(J_[[k]]) = Embedding
    
  }
  BestCoefficients = list()
  BestCoefficients$J = J_
  BestCoefficients$c0 = C0_
  BestParameters = list()
  BestParameters$BestTH = theta_opt
  BestParameters$BestLM = lambda_opt
  return(list(BestCoefficients = BestCoefficients, BestParameters = BestParameters))
}
  
#####Compute the jacobian
Jacobian_ <- function(cl, X, TargetList, Embedding, grid, RegressionType,alpha){
  J = c0 = list()
  th = lm = c()
  n_ = 1
  FUN = match.fun(RegressionType)
  for(trg in TargetList){
    RegularizedParameters <- LOOCrossValidation(cl, X, trg, Embedding, grid, RegressionType,alpha)
    ########## Now compute the optimum regularized coefficients
    J[[n_]]  = FUN(X, trg, Embedding, RegularizedParameters$BestTH, RegularizedParameters$BestLM,alpha)
    th = c(th, RegularizedParameters$BestTH)
    lm = c(lm, RegularizedParameters$BestLM)
    c0[[n_]] = J[[n_]]$c0
    J[[n_]] = J[[n_]][-1]
    n_ = n_ + 1
  }
  return(list(J = J, c0 = c0, th = th, lm = lm))
}
```

In order to compute the elastic-net regularization function you may use this formula (SOURCE 3):

```
ELNET_fit_ <- function(time.series, targ_col, Embedding, theta, lambda,alp){
  Edim <- length(Embedding)
  coeff_names <- sapply(colnames(time.series),function(x) paste("d", targ_col, "d", x, sep = ""))
  block <- cbind(time.series[2:dim(time.series)[1],targ_col],time.series[1:(dim(time.series)[1]-1),])
  block <- as.data.frame(apply(block, 2, function(x) (x-mean(x))/sd(x)))
  
  lib <- 1:dim(block)[1]
  pred <- 1:dim(block)[1]
  
  coeff <- array(0,dim=c(length(pred),Edim + 1))
  colnames(coeff) <- c('c0', coeff_names)
  coeff <- as.data.frame(coeff)
  
  for (ipred in 1:length(pred)){
    libs = lib[-pred[ipred]]
    q <- matrix(as.numeric(block[pred[ipred],2:dim(block)[2]]),
                ncol=Edim, nrow=length(libs), byrow = T)
    distances <- sqrt(rowSums((block[libs,2:dim(block)[2]] - q)^2))
    ### Kernel
    Krnl = match.fun(Regression.Kernel)
    Ws = Krnl(distances, theta)
    ############ Fit function
    x = as.matrix(block[libs,2:dim(block)[2]])
    y = as.matrix(block[libs,1])
    x = x[seq_along(y), ]
    y = y[seq_along(y)]
    Ws = Ws[seq_along(y)]
    x = Ws * cbind(1, x)
    y = Ws * y
    fit <- enet(x, y, lambda = lambda, normalize = TRUE, intercept = FALSE)
    coeff[ipred,] <- predict(fit, s = alp, type="coefficients", mode="fraction")$coefficients 
  }
  return(coeff)
}

ELNET_fit_ <- cmpfun(ELNET_fit_)
```

The auxiliary formulas for computation are as follows (SOURCE 4):

```
TakeLag <- function(X, species.to.lag, num.lag){
  tmp = matrix(0, nrow(X), num.lag)
  tmp[,1] = X[,species.to.lag]
  tmp[1, 1] = NA
  tmp[2:nrow(X), 1] = X[1:(nrow(X) - 1), species.to.lag]
  if(num.lag > 1){
    for(lag. in 2:num.lag){
      tmp[,lag.] = X[,species.to.lag]
      tmp[1, lag.] = NA
      tmp[2:nrow(X), lag.] = tmp[1:(nrow(tmp) - 1), lag.-1]
    }
  }
  tmp
}
make.lagged.ts <- function(X,sp.lag.selection ){
  ### X = time series
  ### sp.lag is a vector whose entry are the lags of each variable
  ### e.g., sp.lag = c(x.lag, y.lag, ..., u.lag)
  s = list()
  for(i in 1:length(sp.lag.selection)){
    Lag.sp = TakeLag(X, original.Embedding[i], sp.lag.selection[i])
    s[[i]] = cbind(X[,original.Embedding[i]], Lag.sp)
  }
  X = do.call(cbind,s)
  ### Remove the NA
  X = X[-c(1:max(sp.lag.selection)),]
  ### Save the position of the unlagged variables
  original.col = c()
  for(k in 1:length(sp.lag.selection)){
    if(k == 1){ original.col = c(original.col, 1)}else{
      num.lags = sum(unlist(lapply(1:(k-1), function(x,X) X[x], sp.lag.selection)))
      original.col = c(original.col, k + num.lags )
    }
  }
  return(list(time.series = X, original.variables = original.col))
}

take.coeff <- function(X, col.to.extract, original.emb){
  ### To use when prediction are made using lagged variables
  ### Take as input the sequence X of Jacobian along the attractor
  ### and the species to look at
  ### return a new sequence of Jacobian of the interaction among those species
  m = lapply(1:length(X$J), function(t, M, specie) M$J[[t]][specie,specie], 
                X, col.to.extract)
  for(i in 1:length(m)){
    colnames(m[[i]]) = rownames(m[[i]]) =original.emb
  }
  return(m)
}

Standardizza <- function(X){
  ### This return y = (x-meanx)/stdx
  for(i in 1:ncol(X)){
    X[,i] = (X[,i]- mean(X[,i]))/sd(X[,i])
  }
  return(X)
}
Standardizza.test <- function(X, Y){
  ### X = test set
  ### Y = training set
  ### This return y = (x-meanY)/stdY
  for(i in 1:ncol(X)){
    X[,i] = (X[,i]- mean(Y[,i]))/sd(Y[,i])
  }
  return(X)
}
###########################
#### Here you compute the quality of the forecast as mean correlation coefficient
```

The problem in the main code sounds like: object 'Regression.Kernel' not found, but I see it in the code, it's written. Maybe the problem is connected with the type of it? But if I take away the quotes in order to make it a "closure", I cannot impose the function restrictions.

Please, help me if you can as I don't know how to solve.

The original dataset ("final_ts.txt"):

```
decy Temp CTD_S OxFix Pro Syn Piceu Naneu
  2011.74221     27.60333     36.20700     27.26667  58638.33333  13107.00000    799.66667    117.66667
  2011.74401     26.97950     36.13400     27.05000  71392.50000  13228.50000   1149.00000    116.50000
  2011.74617     24.99750     35.34450     24.80000 264292.00000  27514.00000   2434.50000    132.50000
  2011.74692     24.78400     35.25800     25.82500 208996.50000  39284.00000   3761.75000    220.75000
  2011.74774     27.34225     35.86800     27.82500 114617.25000  23115.00000   2337.00000    139.75000
  2011.74950     26.47875     36.18175     27.20000  97008.00000   9775.75000    855.50000     77.50000
  2011.75583     26.86500     36.14575     27.47500  76255.00000  10226.75000    783.00000     99.50000
  2011.75654     27.04550     36.04950     27.60000  95017.75000  10546.25000    915.25000     77.75000
  2011.75962     27.06567     36.46367     26.56667  75750.00000  10194.33333    687.00000     44.00000
```

Please, help if you have any guess as I don't have an idea what has gone wrong.

I also provide the full code TO TRY TO RUN (please, try to run it, as I pulled all the sources' codes in one code below):

```
rm(list=ls(all=TRUE)) 
suppressMessages(library(Matrix))
suppressMessages(library(quantreg))
suppressMessages(library(parallel))
suppressMessages(library(compiler))
suppressMessages(library(lars))
suppressMessages(library(elasticnet))
suppressMessages(library(caret))
options(warn=-1)

###########
ShowPlot = FALSE
lags = TRUE

######
### To make next step prediction
Testing <- function(C, C0, X){
  c0 = C0[nrow(C0), ]
  J = C[[length(C)]]
  return(c0 + J%*%X)
}
Add_to_TS <- function(TS, x){
  return(rbind(TS, x))
}
TakeLag <- function(X, species.to.lag, num.lag){
  tmp = matrix(0, nrow(X), num.lag)
  tmp[,1] = X[,species.to.lag]
  tmp[1, 1] = NA
  tmp[2:nrow(X), 1] = X[1:(nrow(X) - 1), species.to.lag]
  if(num.lag > 1){
    for(lag. in 2:num.lag){
      tmp[,lag.] = X[,species.to.lag]
      tmp[1, lag.] = NA
      tmp[2:nrow(X), lag.] = tmp[1:(nrow(tmp) - 1), lag.-1]
    }
  }
  tmp
}
make.lagged.ts <- function(X,sp.lag.selection ){
  ### X = time series
  ### sp.lag is a vector whose entry are the lags of each variable
  ### e.g., sp.lag = c(x.lag, y.lag, ..., u.lag)
  s = list()
  for(i in 1:length(sp.lag.selection)){
    Lag.sp = TakeLag(X, original.Embedding[i], sp.lag.selection[i])
    s[[i]] = cbind(X[,original.Embedding[i]], Lag.sp)
  }
  X = do.call(cbind,s)
  ### Remove the NA
  X = X[-c(1:max(sp.lag.selection)),]
  ### Save the position of the unlagged variables
  original.col = c()
  for(k in 1:length(sp.lag.selection)){
    if(k == 1){ original.col = c(original.col, 1)}else{
      num.lags = sum(unlist(lapply(1:(k-1), function(x,X) X[x], sp.lag.selection)))
      original.col = c(original.col, k + num.lags )
    }
  }
  return(list(time.series = X, original.variables = original.col))
}

take.coeff <- function(X, col.to.extract, original.emb){
  ### To use when prediction are made using lagged variables
  ### Take as input the sequence X of Jacobian along the attractor
  ### and the species to look at
  ### return a new sequence of Jacobian of the interaction among those species
  m = lapply(1:length(X$J), function(t, M, specie) M$J[[t]][specie,specie], 
             X, col.to.extract)
  for(i in 1:length(m)){
    colnames(m[[i]]) = rownames(m[[i]]) =original.emb
  }
  return(m)
}
naive.forecast <- function(last.point.training, test.set){
  #### Return the naive forecast, i.e., the test set is the last point of the training set
  naive.pred = matrix(0,nrow(test.set), ncol(test.set))
  for(j in 1:ncol(naive.pred)){
    naive.pred[,j] = rep(last.point.training[j], nrow(naive.pred))  
  }
  return(compute.rmse.test(naive.pred, test.set))
}
### Compute the rmse between two multivariate time series
compute.rmse.train <- function(X, Y){
  X = X[-1,]
  rmse = c()
  for(i in 1:ncol(X)){
    combine_xy = cbind(X[,i], Y[,i])
    rmse = c(rmse, sqrt(mean(unlist(lapply(1:nrow(combine_xy), 
                                           function(x, A) (A[x,1] - A[x,2])^2, combine_xy)))))
  }
  return(mean(rmse))
}
compute.rmse.test <- function(X, Y){
  rmse = c()
  for(i in 1:ncol(X)){
    combine_xy = cbind(X[,i], Y[,i])
    rmse = c(rmse, sqrt(mean(unlist(lapply(1:nrow(combine_xy), 
                                           function(x, A) (A[x,1] - A[x,2])^2, combine_xy)))))
  }
  return(mean(rmse))
}

ReadTimeSeries <- function(Nome){
  X = as.matrix(read.table(Nome))
  colnames(X) =  LETTERS[1:ncol(X)]
  return(X)
}
Standardizza <- function(X){
  ### This return y = (x-meanx)/stdx
  for(i in 1:ncol(X)){
    X[,i] = (X[,i]- mean(X[,i]))/sd(X[,i])
  }
  return(X)
}
Standardizza.test <- function(X, Y){
  ### X = test set
  ### Y = training set
  ### This return y = (x-meanY)/stdY
  for(i in 1:ncol(X)){
    X[,i] = (X[,i]- mean(Y[,i]))/sd(Y[,i])
  }
  return(X)
}
###########################
#### Here you compute the quality of the forecast as mean correlation coefficient
#### And we set to zero all those forecast that predict an extinction
MeanCorrelation <- function(TS, X){
  rho  = c()
  for(i in 1:ncol(X)){
    rho = c(rho, cor(TS[,i], X[,i]))
  }
  return(mean(rho))
}

##########
LOOCrossValidation <- function(cl, data.df, targ.sp, Embedding, grid, RegressionType,alpha){
  #### It is a bit long but at least you are sure that paralelizzation does not mess things up
  S_target <- parLapply(cl, 1:nrow(grid), CV, data.df, targ.sp, Embedding, grid, RegressionType,alpha)
  error.mat = cbind(unlist(S_target)[attr(unlist(S_target),"names") == "bndwth"],
                    unlist(S_target)[attr(unlist(S_target),"names") == "lmb"],
                    unlist(S_target)[attr(unlist(S_target),"names") == "mse"])
  rownames(error.mat) = c()
  error.mat[,3] = round(error.mat[,3],4)
  error.mat = error.mat[order(error.mat[,3]), ]
  idx = which(error.mat[,3] == min(error.mat[,3]))
  idx.th = which(grid[idx,1] == min(grid[idx,1]))
  idx = idx[min(idx.th)]
  return(list(BestTH = error.mat[idx,1],
              BestLM = error.mat[idx,2],
              min.var.err = error.mat[idx,3],
              val.err = error.mat))
}
#################################################
CV <- function(i, time_series_training, target_species, Embedding, TL, RegressionType,alpha){
  FUN = match.fun(RegressionType)
  #### Fit the model
  coefficients = FUN(time_series_training, target_species, Embedding, TL[i,1], TL[i,2],alpha)
  #### Take the variables in the time series that belong to the embedding
  time_series_training = time_series_training[,Embedding]
  #### Standardize the time series
  time_series_training = Standardizza(time_series_training)
  #### Take the forecast
  Data = Forecast_SMap(coefficients, time_series_training)
  time_series_training = time_series_training[-1,]
  Data = Data[-length(Data)]
  D = cbind(time_series_training[,target_species], Data)
  #### Compute the mean square error
  MSE = mean(unlist(lapply(1:nrow(D), function(x, A) (A[x,1] - A[x,2])^2, D)))
  #return(MSE)
  return(list(mse = MSE, bndwth = TL[i,1], lmb = TL[i,2]))
}

######################################################
Forecast_SMap <- function(C, X){
  n_coeff = ncol(X)
  predizione = c()
  for(k in 1:nrow(X)){
    s = unlist(lapply(1:n_coeff, function(x, J, i) return(J[[x + 1]][i]), C, k))
    predizione = c(predizione, C[[1]][k] + s%*%X[k,])
  }
  return(predizione)
}

Jacobian_ <- function(cl, X, TargetList, Embedding, grid, RegressionType,alpha){
  J = c0 = list()
  th = lm = c()
  n_ = 1
  FUN = match.fun(RegressionType)
  for(trg in TargetList){
    RegularizedParameters <- LOOCrossValidation(cl, X, trg, Embedding, grid, RegressionType,alpha)
    ########## Now compute the optimum regularized coefficients
    J[[n_]]  = FUN(X, trg, Embedding, RegularizedParameters$BestTH, RegularizedParameters$BestLM,alpha)
    th = c(th, RegularizedParameters$BestTH)
    lm = c(lm, RegularizedParameters$BestLM)
    c0[[n_]] = J[[n_]]$c0
    J[[n_]] = J[[n_]][-1]
    n_ = n_ + 1
  }
  return(list(J = J, c0 = c0, th = th, lm = lm))
}

Reconstructing <- function(J, C0, X){
  return(C0 + matrix(unlist(J),length(X), length(X)) %*% X)
}
###
RootMeanSquareError <- function(X, Y){
  rmse <- unlist(lapply(1:length(X), function(x, X, Y) (X[x] - Y[x])^2, X, Y))
  return(sqrt(mean(rmse)))
}
###
ReconstructionOfTrainingSet <- function(TimeSeries, Jac){
  prd = c()
  TimeSeries = Standardizza(TimeSeries)
  for(i in 1:(nrow(TimeSeries) - 1)){
    prd <- rbind(prd, t(Reconstructing(Jac$J[i], Jac$c0[i,], TimeSeries[i,])))
  }
  return(prd)
}
#####################################################################
#####################################################################
ComputeTrainingError <- function(TimeSeries, Jac, real.var){
  ############ First I check how the reconstructed time series looks like
  rmse = rho = c()
  TimeSeries = Standardizza(TimeSeries)
  prd = ReconstructionOfTrainingSet(TimeSeries, Jac)
  ########################################################################
  for(i in real.var){
    #### Important: you need to remove the first point because you 
    #### are making in sample predictions
    observed = TimeSeries[,i]
    observed = observed[-1]
    rmse = c(rmse, RootMeanSquareError(prd[,i], observed))
    rho = c(rho, cor(prd[,i], observed))
  }
  return(list(rmse = median(rmse), rho = median(rho)))
}

ELNET_fit_ <- function(time.series, targ_col, Embedding, theta, lambda,alp){
  Edim <- length(Embedding)
  coeff_names <- sapply(colnames(time.series),function(x) paste("d", targ_col, "d", x, sep = ""))
  block <- cbind(time.series[2:dim(time.series)[1],targ_col],time.series[1:(dim(time.series)[1]-1),])
  block <- as.data.frame(apply(block, 2, function(x) (x-mean(x))/sd(x)))
  
  lib <- 1:dim(block)[1]
  pred <- 1:dim(block)[1]
  
  coeff <- array(0,dim=c(length(pred),Edim + 1))
  colnames(coeff) <- c('c0', coeff_names)
  coeff <- as.data.frame(coeff)
  
  for (ipred in 1:length(pred)){
    libs = lib[-pred[ipred]]
    q <- matrix(as.numeric(block[pred[ipred],2:dim(block)[2]]),
                ncol=Edim, nrow=length(libs), byrow = T)
    distances <- sqrt(rowSums((block[libs,2:dim(block)[2]] - q)^2))
    ### Kernel
    Exponential.Kernel <- function(dst, theta){
      dbar <- mean(dst)
      krnl <- exp(-theta*dst/dbar)
      return(krnl)
    }
    
    Krnl = match.fun(Exponential.Kernel)
    Ws = Krnl(distances, theta)
    ############ Fit function
    x = as.matrix(block[libs,2:dim(block)[2]])
    y = as.matrix(block[libs,1])
    x = x[seq_along(y), ]
    y = y[seq_along(y)]
    Ws = Ws[seq_along(y)]
    x = Ws * cbind(1, x)
    y = Ws * y
    fit <- enet(x, y, lambda = lambda, normalize = TRUE, intercept = FALSE)
    coeff[ipred,] <- predict(fit, s = alp, type="coefficients", mode="fraction")$coefficients 
  }
  return(coeff)
}

ELNET_fit_ <- cmpfun(ELNET_fit_)

ModelName = 'final_ts'
FileName = paste(ModelName, '.txt', sep = '')
###################################
logspace <- function(d1, d2, n) exp(log(10)*seq(d1, d2, length.out=n)) 
std_err <- function(x) sd(x)/sqrt(length(x))
############# Choose the kernel

############# Parameters for cross validation
lambda = logspace(-3,0,15) 
#if(Regression.Kernel == 'Exponential.Kernel'){
tht = seq(from = 0., to = 10, length = 30)         
#}else{
#  tht = seq(from = 0.1, to = 3, length = 20)     
#}
parameters_on_grid = expand.grid(tht, lambda)

### Read Time series
d = as.matrix(read.table(FileName, header= T))
######################
original.Embedding = c('Pro', 'Syn','Piceu')
original.TargetList = original.Embedding
d = d[, original.Embedding]
#### Here you take combinations of lags (best lag are 1 - 2)
x.lag = 1; y.lag = 2; z.lag = 1
sp.lag.selection = c(x.lag, y.lag, z.lag)
lagged.time.series = make.lagged.ts(d, sp.lag.selection)
d = lagged.time.series$time.series
original.col = lagged.time.series$original.variables
if(lags == TRUE){ var.sel = original.col; }else{ var.sel = colnames(d)}
##### Names and embedding in the laged dataset
if(lags == TRUE){ colnames(d) = Embedding =  TargetList = LETTERS[1:ncol(d)]}else{
  Embedding =  TargetList = original.Embedding
}
##### length of training and test set
length.testing = 2
length.training = nrow(d) - length.testing
#### Preserve training for the interactions
ts.train.preserved = d[1:length.training, var.sel]
std.ts.train = Standardizza(ts.train.preserved)
#### Preserve testing for the test (you want your algorithm to learn the real structure of the model)
ts.test.preserved = d[(length.training + 1):nrow(d), var.sel]
#### Training set:
d.training = Standardizza(d[1:length.training, ])
#### You now need to standardize the test set using mean and sd of the training set
d.testing = Standardizza.test(ts.test.preserved,ts.train.preserved)
############## Prepare for parallel computing
Lavoratori = detectCores() - 2
cl <- parallel::makeCluster(Lavoratori, setup_strategy = "sequential")
####
RegressionType = ELNET_fit_
#RegressionType = ridge_fit_
alpha = 0.85
parameters_on_grid = expand.grid(tht, lambda)
lambda = logspace(-3,0,15)
tht = seq(from = 0., to = 10, length = 30)
### should you compute all the variables or not?

BestModelLOOCV <- function(cl, X, TargetList, Embedding, grid, RegressionType,alpha){
  mine_output = Jacobian_(cl, X, TargetList, Embedding, grid, RegressionType,alpha)
  theta_opt = mine_output$th
  lambda_opt = mine_output$lm
  mine_c0  = mine_output$c0
  mine_output = mine_output$J
  
  J_ = list()
  C0_ = do.call(cbind, lapply(1:ncol(X), function(x, M) unlist(M[[x]]), mine_c0))
  colnames(C0_) = sapply(TargetList,function(x) paste("c0_", x, sep = ""))
  for(k in 1:(nrow(X) - 1)){
    J_[[k]] = do.call(rbind, lapply(1:ncol(X), function(x, M, i) unlist(M[[x]][i,]), mine_output, k))
    rownames(J_[[k]]) = Embedding
    colnames(J_[[k]]) = Embedding
    
  }
  BestCoefficients = list()
  BestCoefficients$J = J_
  BestCoefficients$c0 = C0_
  BestParameters = list()
  BestParameters$BestTH = theta_opt
  BestParameters$BestLM = lambda_opt
  return(list(BestCoefficients = BestCoefficients, BestParameters = BestParameters))
}

BestModel = BestModelLOOCV(cl, d.training, TargetList = TargetList, Embedding = Embedding, grid = parameters_on_grid, RegressionType = RegressionType, alpha = alpha)
```

Answer (score 2):

When you call

```r
BestModel = BestModelLOOCV(cl, d.training, TargetList, Embedding, parameters_on_grid)
```

It is silently ignoring the fact that your `BestModelLOOCV` function has two more arguments,

```r
BestModelLOOCV <- function(cl, X, TargetList, Embedding, grid, RegressionType,alpha){
 ...
}
```

In this case, a few lines into the function you then call `match.fun(RegressionType)` which forces it. Not finding it, it fails.

Fix it by adding it to your call, you should also add `alpha` as well.

```r
BestModel = BestModelLOOCV(cl, d.training, TargetList, Embedding, parameters_on_grid
  RegressionType = RegressionType, alpha = alpha)
```

The naming is optional here, I added them call-by-name just for demonstration.

Comment: @Axeman, I tried to do what you said, but it didn't work - it still cannot find the Regression.Kernel

Comment: (1) Axeman did not write the answer, r2evans did (me). (2) It worked for me. In your code block above, you define `RegressionType = ELNET_fit_` before calling `BestModelLOOVC`, so it exists. I suggest you learn a little more about the script(s) you're running and call it line-by-line to see where the issue is.

Comment: sorry for the mistake. Thank you!

Comment: I tried to change the match.fun(Regression.Kernel) to `match.fun(Exponential.Kernel)`, added the `Exponential.Kernel` function to the `ELNET_fit_` function. First, it didn't work, as after it found the `Exponential.kernel` (as far as I understood, the problem just didn't show) the code couldn't find the `enet` function, but I imported the `elastic net` package beforehand. I even put all the code above in one file and the problem is the same. I called the code line-by-line, and I think the problem is inside the ELNET_fit_ part. Maybe you have other options why the problem exists?

Comment: I also added the full code (see in the end of the question and sorry as it's so long, please try to run to see what happens (`enet` object is not found) )

Comment: I put everything in one code and in the places where the code couldn't find the function I put the function before the questionable part and it worked! That's a silly way, but it worked! Thank you for help anyway!